# Is it possible to execute all make commands that match a pattern?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I define several make PHONY commands:

```
auto-build-foo
auto-build-bar
auto-build-biz
...
auto-build-inf
```

And I can observe them all with the following keystrokes in `bash` with `autocompletion` configured:

```
$: make auto-build-<tab><tab>
auto-build-foo
auto-build-bar
auto-build-biz
...
auto-build-inf
```

Then my natural unix instinct is to write:

```
make auto-build-*
```

To build them all.

---

I understand this sort of thing needs to be implemented in `make` as a feature, a `makefile` as some sort of rule system, or some custom shell that integrates `bash-completion` history with some `make`-specialized interpretation.

But it would cool and useful to get this "out-of-the-box".

Is there such a mechanism that is -- or will be -- in GNU make?

Answer (score 0):

No, GNU Make command line argument do not support wildcard.

But, you can easily do the job in `bash`:

- One by one

`$ for t in $(sed -e '/auto-build/!d' -e 's/:.*$//' -e 's/\n/ /' Makefile); do make  "$t" ; done`

- At once

`$ my_targets=$(sed -e '/auto-build/!d' -e 's/:.*$//' -e 's/\n/ /' Makefile)`

`$ make "$my_targets"`

From a Makefile perspective, if you create your own, an efficient way could be to encapsulate the targets in a variable each time you write them:

```
TARGET:=auto-build-foo
$(TARGET):
    @echo "$@"

ALL_TARGETS:=$(ALL_TARGETS) $(TARGET)

TARGET:=auto-build-bar
$(TARGET):
    @echo "$@"

ALL_TARGETS:=$(ALL_TARGETS) $(TARGET)

auto-all: $(ALL_TARGETS)

.PHONY: auto-all
```

will give:

```
$ make auto-all
auto-build-foo
auto-build-bar
```

Comment: I appreciate it, but this seems like it is outside the constraints.  The idea is to have something "athletic" that is effortless from the fingertips. So I'll continue to think about this one and implementing it.

Comment: I'm afraid it could be very risky: what rule will come at first ? Anyway ? alphabetical ? If you don't write explicit rules/dependencies, how `gnu make` could figure out the order of targets ? Your request is a bit twisted.Anyway, thanks for your appreciation, and sorry to not answer your question.

Comment: Yes it requires a restriction and some discipline.

Answer (score 0):

I think such a feature doesn't exist because many makefiles are written with an incomplete dependency graph; command line parameters - which tend to be recorded nowhere - are the main reason for this. Targets built for `foo` may introduce bugs when being reused as-is for `bar` - the usual procedure is to require an intermediate `make clean` to prevent this. The problem is that, given the current (and unlikely to change) execution logic of `make`, within one run there is no way to execute `clean` more than once, much less in an order which would not defy the purpose of `make` (partial updates) at all. I think the original use case for makefiles was more around single-purpose project building rather than a cross-over of dependency and batch processing. From a modern build system perspective this looks like a shortcoming, OTOH it is this focused simplicity which makes it the means of choice for many projects.

Comment: Yeah, I think the entrypoint for something like this could be fulfilled at the bash-tooling layer rather than make itself. For my purposes, I use make as a "super-" language for scripts, docker, git, npm, python, data maneuvers, project management, CICD commands, etc. And when I use it in that way, I can define rules to be order independent with useful names for globbing. But, perhaps I am one of the only people using make as an automation language.

Comment: @Chris by pure coincidence (tm) I wrote a build system for the exact same purpose. It consists of a two-layered approach: the upper (project) layer defines a dependency tree the parts of which get reevaluated in case they are multiply linked (the exact contrary to what make does) and the lower layer consists of either plain vanilla makefiles or, if you want it simpler and controllable, a collection of restricted one-recipe-only tasks. It was also invented for CI/CD. (btw it's called "nope" - the usual reply when I asked our developers if they wanted to try my new build system)

Comment: Love it -- I'll give it a spin

Comment: Do you have a github link?

Comment: @Chris I need to ask if I can put it into OSS - BTW which license would you recommend, and is there a non-partisan guide to which license is sensible for which scenario?

Comment: One of the guys at my gym is the president of tech law for the state bar association.  I'll ask him if he has any advice next week.  Otherwise, MiT is a good place to start looking into if you don't want to release it completely with GNU.  Some of the other licenses can be more restrictive, and the projects with more restrictive licenses seem to become more obscure and less used.

Comment: For a good, high level overview: https://medium.com/nationwide-technology/a-short-guide-to-open-source-licenses-cf5b1c329edd